# bootstrap scrollable dropdown menu with fixed last element after separator

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap3 with dropdown menu. I wanna have the list items scrollable except the last one (after the separator) which always should be visible and fixed at the end of the list. I have the following code at the moment and my problem is that with this code the last element is also scrollable and I don't know what I should do.

What should I change in the code?

```
<ul class = "dropdown-menu scrollable-bootstrap-menu">
  <li><a href='#'>item1</a></li>         //from here
  <li><a href='#'>item2</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>item3</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>item4</a></li>        //to here should be scrollable
  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href='#'>View all items</a></li> //should be non scrollable (always visible/fixed)
</ul>
```

css

```
.scrollable-bootstrap-menu {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: try last child selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way that I know to do this is to have a list within a list. Like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-bootstrap-menu">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>item1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item3</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href='#'>View all items</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then set the inner list one to scroll on overflow.

```
.scrollable-bootstrap-menu ul {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Here's a demo (without much styling, but it works):

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/vyLk778k/)

Or check the full code below:

```css
.scrollable-bootstrap-menu ul {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-bootstrap-menu">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>item1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item3</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href='#'>View all items</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Chris, do you know an easy way to extend the bootstrap styling to the nested list as well?

Comment: Yes, just add "class=scrollable-bootstrap-menu" to the nested ul as well. Then change the css to "ul li ul" instead of ".scrollable-bootstrap-menu ul"

Comment: This way you change to code manually, so it doesn't inherit from bootstrap, right?

Comment: Correct. Otherwise both the parent and child list would get the same effect.

Comment: Thanks! I will play around with the css and try to find the bootstrap source code to have the same style with the nested list.

Comment: While it's perfectly possible to do that, I do advice against it. Don't edit source code. Instead import bootstrap in your project and then your own css. Because of CSS cascading nature, if 2 or more rules are found for one element, the first css will be overwritten with the rules of the 2nd.

Comment: I will only edit my css, just want to see what properties are defined in the source code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:
css:

```
.scrollable-bootstrap-menu {
height: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
position:relative;
}
.scrollable-bootstrap-menu li:last-child {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```

js:

```
$('.scrollable-bootstrap-menu').scroll(function(){
$('.scrollable-bootstrap-menu li:last-child').css('bottom',-$(this).scrollTop());

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vyLk778k/1/